# 403 forbidden error when calling durable function status query via Azure API Management Service

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, azure-durable-functions

I have an Azure Durable Functions Orchestration function configured and running in Azure.

I also have an Azure API Management Service configured to expose the orchestration function.

I can successfully call the orchestration function via the Azure API Management Service and get the 202 accepted and the Location header with the status query GET URL to poll until the orchestration function completes/fails etc.

If I call the relevant status query GET URL directly to the Azure function: e.g. https://some-ulr-to-the-function-app.azurewebsites.net/runtime/webhooks/durabletask/instances/cc970c6e2cb2426f99629c17cdd12345?code=q4NnjCbKTdBdH6712345dm4tnRRlYEAZ2tnZUliepmIKAzFuNUC0MQ==

I get a 200 response and the current status of the orchestration is as expected

If I try and expose this endpoint via the Azure API Management Service and attempt to get the status I get a 403 forbidden response. e.g. https://some-ulr-to-apim-service.azure-api.net/runtime/webhooks/durabletask/instances/cc970c6e2cb2426f99629c17cdd12345?code=q4NnjCbKTdBdH6712345dm4tnRRlYEAZ2tnZUliepmIKAzFuNUC0MQ==

So can this, /runtime/webhooks/durabletask/instances/cc970c6e2cb2426f99629c17cdd12345?code=q4NnjCbKTdBdH6712345dm4tnRRlYEAZ2tnZUliepmIKAzFuNUC0MQ==, endpoint be exposed via the Azure API Management Service? If so what should I look to be configuring to be able to expose this endpoint via the Azure API Management service?

Any other way to use APIM to run a durable function app status query?

Any help would be much appreciated

Direct function app status query works but not through APIM.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to expose the relevant **`statusQueryGetUri`** endpoint via APIM and got the expected output as well by following the below steps-

1. Added an operation:

[image]

2. Added **`statusQueryGetUri`** as a backend endpoint

[image]

[image]

**`Output:`**

Not passing any header or query parameter

[image]

[image]

[image]